# How To Upload A File To Google Drive Using Google API From Console Application c# (Note - Need to upload from Console Application)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, google-drive-api, console-application

I have a Job (Console application in C#) which run daily (Scheduled on Window Job Task Scheduler), It generate a file (.xls, xlsx), I need to upload this file to Google drive after the generation. Please help me on it, how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check how to [Perform a simple upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple) reference, which you have on .NET:

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "photo.jpg"
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/photo.jpg",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

To know how to call Drive API from .NET I recommend you to go through the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) where you have to enable the API and then set-up the sample so see how it works.

Comment: You should not only give raw links, but provide an answer that can survive dead links : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you, This code is working fine, but it is asking first time to download the Token in MyAppToken folder which required Human interaction, I want to avoid the same without using the Service account.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I am struggling with the TeamDrive, I have a requirement to create the folder in TeamDrive, I tried a lot but each time I am getting the issue as below:     Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
File not found: 0APa7okDAhPnuUk9PVA. [404]
Errors [
 Message[File not found: 0APa7okDAhPnuUk9PVA.] Location[fileId - parameter] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]

Comment: it is resolved, I was not setting the property  result.SupportsTeamDrives = true; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize the Google Drive API,
//InitializeGoogleDriveAPIService

```
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, };
        //var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        //var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
        clientSecrets.ClientId = GDriveClientId;
        clientSecrets.ClientSecret = GDriveClientSecret;


        // Below is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%  
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, scopes, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;

        //Once consent is received, the token will be stored locally on the AppData directory,
        //so that next time we won't be prompted for consent. -one time setting for the Console app   

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
        initializer.ApplicationName = "PRInvoices";

        DriveService service = new DriveService(initializer);

        service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
        //Long Operations like file uploads might timeout. 100 is just precautionary value,
        //can be set to any reasonable value depending on what you use your service for  

        return service;
    //

 private Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File UploadFileToGoogleDrive(string sourceFilePath, string driveFolderId = "", string _descrp = "File")
    {
        //If driveFolderId is empty it means it would upload to root directory if you want to upload under a folder, pass folder's id.
        DriveService _service = InitializeGoogleDriveAPIService();
        if (File.Exists(sourceFilePath))
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            body.Name = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
            body.Description = _descrp;
            body.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sourceFilePath);
            body.Parents = new List<string> { driveFolderId };
            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            try
            {
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Create(body, stream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sourceFilePath));
                request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
                request.Upload();
                return request.ResponseBody;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _prTasksPRSaveInvoiceOnGoogleDriveLogger.Error("Warning - Type Fatel - Function -UploadFileToGoogleDrive(), the details of which are: ", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```